# t-sql ado recordset / SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, ado

I want to execute a T-SQL statement with ADO-layer. The sql-statement is like:

```
DECLARE @var TABLE (id int)
INSERT INTO @var SELECT id FROM tblFoo WHERE name='myName' AND idx=2
SELECT * FROM tblFoo WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM @var)
```

In the SQL Server management console all works well. But if I use that for opening a ADO_Recordset  via Open(sql) that recordset will not be filled/opened. eof() said: recordset is not opened.

The question ist: How to exectue T-SQL stataments that will result a recordset   on the ADO layer?

Answer (score 1):

In the `Options` parameter of the `Open()` method you need to pass in `CommandTypeEnum.adCmdText`.

see this link for more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675544(v=vs.85).aspx

Also change your query to this:

```
    SELECT * FROM tblFoo WHERE name='myName' AND idx=2
```

Comment: The commandType is already on adCmdText. (I'm using a very old ADO interface: c++ on ADO 2.7) Yes you are right. That query can be written more easy. But in real the statement may look as: SELECT * FROM tblFoo WHERE pos=4 AND id IN (SELECET id FROM tblFoo WHERE pos=3 AND name='nameForThirdPos') AND id IN (SELECET id FROM tblFoo WHERE pos=2 AND name='nameForSecondPos') 
The table contains a separat record for each name on a specified pos.

Answer (score 0):

You need to treat this SQL as plain test
something like:

```
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
```